# Повторный вызов функции через next_step_handler. Telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Только начал изучение ботостроительства и возник такой вопрос:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
def start_reg(message):
    mrk = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
    bottom_yes = types.KeyboardButton('Да, хочу!')
    bottom_no = types.KeyboardButton('Нет, спасибо')

    mrk.add(bottom_yes, bottom_no)

    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id , "Хочешь стать чатсью него Сообщества?" , reply_markup=mrk)

    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg , answer)


def answer(message):
    if message.text == 'Да, хочу!':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Тогда заполните ГУГЛ ФОРМУ(Ссылка на гугл форму)."
                                                "В ближайшее время наши модераторы напишут Вам! До скорого!")
    elif message.text == 'Нет, спасибо':
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'А теперь открой диалоговое окно справа и выбери нормально!')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, try_two)


def try_two():
    pass

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтоб после "Нет ,спасибо" , человек открыл клавиатуру справа выбрав "Да" перешёл дальше. Или чтоб `bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, try_two)`перекидывала на функцию , где будет только одна кнопка "Да".

Вообще буду очень благодарен любым советам и комментариям, как лучше это сделать, так как только только начинаю практиковаться.
Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пробуй

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_reg(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
    markup.add('Да, хочу!', 'Нет, спасибо')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Хочешь стать чатсью него Сообщества?", reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, answer)


def answer(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == 'Да, хочу!':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Тогда заполните ГУГЛ ФОРМУ(Ссылка на гугл форму)."
                                          "В ближайшее время наши модераторы напишут Вам! До скорого!")
    elif message.text == 'Нет, спасибо':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'А теперь открой диалоговое окно справа и выбери нормально!')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, answer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.infinity_polling(skip_pending=True)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Всё отработало и очень просто оказалось!) Просто сослаться на эту же функцию.
Я ещё придумал решение: после "нет спасибо" сразу создать клавиатуру с одним уже вариантом ответа и всё также отработало.